# How to extract content from curly brackets to arraylists

Tags: java

I need to extract the string between curly brackets like so, for instance `{3{4 5}6}`

Then

- List A would contain 3 and 6
- List B would contain 4 and 5
- List C contains List A and B

I've tried removing curly brackets but I can only manage to do it when I have only one pair of curly brackets; when I have something like the example above it just makes it into one list and list B is empty.

Comment: Please improve your question by showing your best attempt at a solution and explaining the specific problems you're having with it.

Comment: Hi Jakie - welcome.  Please be sure to read "How to Ask".  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - your question will get better traction if you observe some basic formatting and content suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate lists from the curly brace notation of lists you have, you can follow a simple stack-based algorithm to generate a final list of lists.

Notice that when you have input like the following string,

```
"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"
```

and you start traversing from the first character, you can see that you have to start a new list whenever you encounter opening curly brace like '{'. Similarly, when you encounter a closing brace '}', you have to close a previously opened list that you were most recently working on constructing.

For, example, the algorithm will run something like the following:

```
"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"     |          | 
 ^                                     |          |
                                       |    []    | //push new list because you found a '{'
                                         stack

"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"     |          | 
  ^                                    |          |
                                       |    [3]   | //push 3 to topmost list
                                         stack

"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"     |          | 
    ^                                  |    []    |
                                       |    [3]   | //push new list because you found a '{'
                                         stack

"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"     |          | 
     ^                                 |    [4]   |
                                       |    [3]   | // push 4 to topmost list
                                         stack

"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"     |          | 
       ^                               |    [4 5] |
                                       |    [3]   | //push 5 to topmost list
                                         stack

"{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}"     |          | 
        ^                              |          | //pop [4 5] and store it
                                       |    [3]   | //because you found a '}'   
                                         stack

... and so on
```

Here is a simple implementation of the algorithm. Note that it will work well only for inputs where all the parenthesis are balanced:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "{3 {4 5} 6 { 5 6 7 8 9} 1 1 1 1}";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = getLists(input);

        for (List<Integer> l1 : result) {
           for (Integer n : l1) {
               System.out.print(n + " "); 
           }

            System.out.println();
        } 
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getLists(String s){
        s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayDeque<ArrayList<Integer>> stack = new ArrayDeque<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == '{'){
                //add new list to stack
                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                stack.push(list);
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) == '}'){
                //pop topmost list from stack and add to result
                result.add(stack.pop());
            }else{
                stack.peek().add(Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)));
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Output of the above algorithm:

```
4 5 
5 6 7 8 9 
3 6 1 1 1 1
```